# emacs navigation to beginning or end of code block

Tags: emacs

in emacs, how can I navigate to the beginning or end of some text like this:

```
test_rejects_requests_when_given_token_is_invalid
```

In vim I would do capital E if in command mode but I am not sure how to do this in emacs.

Comment: use capital E in Evil ! `M-x evil-mode` http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>M-m</kbd> for `back-to-indentation` takes you to the first text part of the line. This is useful since most of the time code is indented and you don't want to go to the actual beginning of the line (like <kbd>C-a</kbd>). As songyuanyao said, <kbd>C-e</kbd> takes you to the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>ctrl-a</kbd> for `move-beginning-of-line`, and <kbd>ctrl-e</kbd> for `move-end-of-line`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `C-M-left` and `C-M-right`, each of which is `backward-sexp` and `forward-sexp`, respectively. If you don't want to use arrow keys, then `C-M-b` and `C-M-f` also works.

Answer (score 0):

Also in this particular scenario, M-f forward word, M-b back a word. Depending on your local definition of a word!